# Moveit - Extract path

Tags: ros, moveit, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the cartesian path planner plugin and it somehow works.
I can visualize the movement for a given goal point.

But how can I extract all the intermediate points from the trajectory?
I would like to plot them.

Alternatively, how could I achieve this without plugin?

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243449/moveit---extract-path/) by [Soho_](https://answers.ros.org/users/27617/soho_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

If you are planning with MoveIt! using the MoveGroupCommander (python/C++), you can inspect the trajectory that was planned. I do this by the following:

```
group_manipulator.set_pose_target(pose_target)  
plan_manipulator = group_manipulator.plan()

print plan_manipulator.joint_trajectory.points.positions
```

More information about joint_trajectory msgs can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html).

This will allow you to inspect the positions of each way point in the trajectory. Rather than printing them to screen, you can plot them with your favorite tool.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Soho_](https://answers.ros.org/users/27617/soho_/) on 2016-09-13**:
oh that sounds great.
do you have the general skeleton of your code?
the moveit tutorial website is down right now for some reason..

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-09-13**:
[python implementation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html)

[c++ implementation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html)

**Comment by [Soho_](https://answers.ros.org/users/27617/soho_/) on 2016-09-14**:
thank you. but I want to use a different robot description.
where should I put my .urdf file?

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-09-14**:
Do you already have a moveit_config package made from your URDF? If not, look at the tutorials with moveit_setup_assistant.